# ROR Activerecord where check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am working on ruby on rails and trying to check database for SIGNIN

here is my code model code

```
def self.signIn(form)
  user=Users.where(username: form[:username], password:form[:password])
  return user
end
```

and my controller code is

```
def sigin_action
@hello = Users.signIn(params)
render :text => @hello
end
```

but the output is always '#' sign, whats the problem, I have searched a lot but couldn't find a solution

Comment: Use `Users.where(username: form[:username], password: form[:password]).first`

Comment: I've added it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some other problems

> 1. Your `Model` should be *singular* (yours is plural)
> 2. You mention you want to *check* the presence of your search - surely you'd be better with [`.exists?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F)

---

**Model**

Firstly, you need to [make sure your model name is `Singular`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html#method-i-model_name)

Although the main reason is for Rails conventions, it serves to provide you with a more robust structure for the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). The importance of this is down to how Rails is built as an [*object orientated*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) framework

Without going into too much detail, let me just say that as you progress with Rails, you'll begin to see evidence of the object orientation of Ruby throughout the framework. This means that every time you perform any method / create any functionality, it will be based around *objects*.

As such, every time you call a "model", you're not calling a class - you're calling an object. That's why models are called singularly - they provide you with the ability to call a series of data from your database, compressing it all into your model object. In the sense of Rails, it gives you the ability to call `User.find 1` to create a new *user* object.

Bottom line: **call your models by their singular name**

---

**Exists**

This probably isn't what you need, but there's another ActiveRecord method called `.exists?` if you want it. This will return a boolean (`true` / `false`) depending on the presence of the data from your query in the db.

When you mention that you want to `check database for SIGNIN`, you would perhaps be better with the following:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.signIn(form)
       return self.exists?(username: form[:username], password: form[:password])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

[ActiveRecord#where](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) returns a relation object. To access the object(s), you can either loop, or if you expect only a single record, call `first`

```
Users.where(username: form[:username], password: form[:password]).first
```

Answer (score 0):

`render :text => @hello` is equal to

```
hello = @hello.to_s
render :text => hello
```

Because `ruby#instance.to_s` will be a `#xxxxx` like string, so you get some text like this.

Think you should render result like :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: @hello }
end
```